How to set padding on a html image on QTextdocument?
I'm trying to set padding to a specific direction for an image being rendered on a QTextDocument, but it ain't working, the image is being drawn with no padding.
I have tried these two ways:
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget*     widget   = new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout* layout   = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
    QTextEdit*   textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);
    QTextDocument* doc = textEdit->document();
    QString html = "hello world <img src=\":/logos/logo.png\""
        "width=\"16\" height=\"16\" style=\"padding-top:10px;\"/>";
    html = "hello world <span style=\"padding-top:10px; display: inline-block;\">"
        "<img src=\":/logos/logo.png\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"/></span>";
    
    doc->setHtml(html);
    widget->show();
    
    return a.exec();
}

The QTextDocument documentation says it supports padding, what could be wrong?
Qt 6.5 Windows

If you read more carefully, the documentation says that it supports padding for table cells. If you want to provide custom geometries for images, you need to use a custom QTextObjectInterface.

@musicamante do you have an example of customizing the position of an image in a QTextDocument according to the text position?

Perhaps the Text Object Example could be of help.

As musicamante said, QTextTable and its cell can adopt padding property. You set html of texttable with 1 row and column and set padding to it. If you can do it, you disguise the document as if it were an usual document. Because a texttable with 1 row and 1 column is almost the same thing as a QTextFrame. And QTextDocument has originally a QTextFrame(rootFrame).
